# How to detect is content Netflix original or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, netflix

I am developing a Chrome extension which provides additional subtitles for Netflix.com

I need to detect the moment when Netflix preload trailer is successfully played.

– For Netflix original content it's 6 seconds from the beginning of the video.

– For third-party content (not Netflix) it's 3 seconds.

Since Netflix API is not available for public I am wondering how to detect if video is "Netflix original" content or not.

Both times links and title don't include special parameters.

Link to Netflix original content ("Orange is the new black" series):

```
https://www.netflix.com/watch/70259443?trackId=14170286&tctx=5%2C1%2C2b463a20-083c-4bc2-99db-5d8a82300233-330725099
```

Link to Non-Netflix original ("Supergirl" series):

```
https://www.netflix.com/watch/80120392?trackId=14170035&tctx=4%2C2%2C2b463a20-083c-4bc2-99db-5d8a82300233-330725099
```

Please, help me to detect the difference. Any ideas?

Comment: If all else fails, you could extract the name of the series from the DOM of the page, do some normalisation, and compare it to a list of original series that you maintain.

Comment: Would you crawl the page with full browser capabilities or just download initial html body payload?

Comment: @enapupe I can see the same data as a user see, so I will see full browser info.

Comment: THis endpoint seems to disclose some credit/recap timing information but I don't see anythink "preload' related: https://www.netflix.com/api/shakti/390873b9/metadata?movieid=70259443&imageFormat=webp&_=1498049651534

Comment: Scrape the title, use omdb/imdb api to find the production house. If netflix, continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scrape the result of those links. Then you can find a javascript variable called `netflix.falcorCache`. Inside that variable, one of the fields is "`isOriginal:true`" or "`isOriginal:false`".

Comment: More precisely within `netflix.falkorCache.videos['videoIDHERE'].summary.isOriginal`

Comment: It's amazing! Even don't know how I didn't see it before!

Comment: Kir, I'm glad to help. If you are right with the answer please mark it as correct (green check). Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Guys, maybe you know how exactly to know the duration of the preloader video (production house preloader)? For Netflix original it's 6 seconds, BBC has 3 seconds preloader, Showtime is almost 13 seconds. Really need to know this duration and/or production company :(